# Wordpress sending data with add_action

Tags: hooks

I am trying to use a function in another function but I don't want to edit the core file so I am trying to add that function with hooks, couldn't figure it out how to send the id.

Below you can see how I did but I am calling my function in the core file.

This is the function in core file: (I added my function manually `create_submerchant ($_GET[ 'user_id' ]);` to use that user's ID)

```
public function user_row_actions_commit()
    {
        if ( !empty( $_GET[ 'action' ] ) && !empty( $_GET[ 'user_id' ] ) ) {

            $wp_user_object = new WP_User( (int) $_GET[ 'user_id' ] );

            switch ( $_GET[ 'action' ] ) {
                case 'approve_vendor':
                    $role = 'vendor';
                    add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'approved' ) );
                    do_action( 'wcvendors_approve_vendor', $wp_user_object );
                    create_submerchant ($_GET[ 'user_id' ]);
                    break;

                case 'deny_vendor':
                    $role = 'customer';
                    add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'denied' ) );
                    do_action( 'wcvendors_deny_vendor', $wp_user_object ); 
                    break;

                default:
                    // code...
                    break;
            }

            $wp_user_object->set_role( $role );

        }
    }
```

My custom function:

```
function create_submerchant($user_id) {

        $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);

        $store_country = 'TR';
        $store_name = $user_info ->pv_shop_name;
        $store_owner_name = $user_info ->_wcv_custom_settings_bankahesapadi;
        $store_owner_lastname = $user_info ->_wcv_custom_settings_bankahesapsoyadi; 
        $store_email = $user_info -> user_email;
        $store_address = $user_info ->_wcv_custom_settings_banka_adres;
        $store_iban = $user_info ->_wcv_custom_settings_bankaiban;
        $store_owner_id = $user_id;
        $store_owner_tc = $user_info ->_wcv_custom_settings_kimlikno;

        create_personal_sub_merchant($store_country,$store_name,$store_owner_name,$store_owner_lastname,$store_email,$store_address,$store_iban,$store_owner_id,$store_owner_tc);

}
```

So how can accomplish this with hooks?

Comment: Hi C. Yasa. Are you trying to bind 'create_submerchant' to an action, then call it with do action? In that case wouldn't `add_action('create_submerchant',array( $this, 'create_submerchant' ) );` followed by `do_action( 'create_submerchant', $_GET[ 'user_id' ] );` do the trick?

Comment: Hi Pedro, I am trying to use `create_submerchant` in side of `case 'approve_vendor':` without editing the `public function user_row_actions_commit()` . When a vendor approves I need to use `create_submerchant` with  $wp_user_object 's `user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested but you should be able to hook into 'wcvendors_approve_vendor' action. It is also passing the $wp_user_object to you which you could get the user id from...OR `$_GET` is a global, so you can still access `$_GET['user_id']` if you wanted.  The '10' in the add_action is the priority and the '1' tells it that there is a parameter passed.

So probably in your `functions.php` you could add the following

```
add_action('wcvendors_approve_vendor', 'your_function', 10, 1);

function your_function($user_object) {
  create_submerchant ($user_object->ID);
}
```